# Could not found kontena-lens from snapstore

Tags: kubernetes, snap

I have been using kontena-lens for monitoring my cluster. But today when i want to install lens on a new computer ubuntu 20.04 when i run command sudo snap install kontena-lens --classic the snap is not found. My question have they removed it from snapstore? have been using this method many times. But today there is no trace of lens anymore. Do someone have any knowledge about this?

sudo apt update
sudo install snapd
sudo snap install kontena-lens --classic

Comment: https://medium.com/@Engineer_Dollery/ubuntu-snap-here-be-dragons-c2cd3b5c9774

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I'm no longer seeing Lens in SNAPs as well (I thought I could not too long ago), but could install it from here in the meantime: https://docs.k8slens.dev/getting-started/install-lens/